# JS background script doesn't start on refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement dark mode feature to my extension and now I'm facing a problem with dark mode after reloading. When I click on the button it changes the website perfectly but after a refresh of the site, I need to click on the extension icon so my saved option can be loaded. Here is content of background.js and manifest.json has  "background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ]. Using chrome.storage.local.set and chrome.storage.local.get gives me error on console. I hope everything is clear :D

```
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('.button_mode');

const enableDarkMode = () => { 
 
 chrome.tabs.executeScript({
   file: 'appOn.js'
})
 localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {  
 chrome.tabs.executeScript({
   file: 'appOff.js'
})
 
 localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}


if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
 enableDarkMode();
} 
darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {

 darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode'); 
 
 if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
   enableDarkMode();
 } else {  
   disableDarkMode(); 
 }
});
```

permissions from manifest

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*", 
    "downloads",
    "storage"
  ]
```

Comment: In a ManifestV2 extension you can use chrome.declarativeContent API with RequestContentScript action to make the content script run automatically. In ManifestV3 it's simply registerContentScripts and unregisterContentScripts in chrome.scripting API.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `background.js` script. At the point where you're doing `darkMode === 'enabled'`, `darkMode` variable isn't initialised yet. It should read the already saved preference from the `localStorage` on page load.
To fix this, you could look at [`chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onCompleted) event.
The code should look like this now:

```
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector('.button_mode');

const enableDarkMode = () => { 
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'appOn.js'
  })
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'enabled');
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {  
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'appOff.js'
  })
  localStorage.setItem('darkMode', null);
}

chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
  (details) => {
    darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
    if (darkMode === 'enabled') {
      enableDarkMode();
    }
  }
)

darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem('darkMode');
  if (darkMode !== 'enabled') {
    enableDarkMode();
  } else {  
    disableDarkMode(); 
  }
});
```